# Running Mantel test in ape with missing values

Tags: error

I am running a Mantel test using the mantel.test in ape package.
In the beginning, I've created distance matrices;

```
dist.mat <- function(distances, dimension)
 {
   x <- matrix(NA, nrow = dimension, ncol = dimension)
   diag(x) <- 0
   lcomb <- matrix(NA, nrow = 1, ncol = 2)
   for(i in 1:nrow(x))
      {
        for(j in 1:ncol(x))
           {
             if(i > j) {lcomb <- rbind(lcomb, c(i, j))}
             j <- j + 1
           }
        i <- i + 1
      }
   lcomb <- lcomb[-1 , ]
   ucomb <- cbind(lcomb[ , 2], lcomb[ , 1])
   for(i in 1:length(distances))
      {
        x[lcomb[i, 1], lcomb[i, 2]] <- distances[i]
        x[ucomb[i, 1], ucomb[i, 2]] <- distances[i]
        i <- i + 1
      }
   x
 }
```

THEN,

```
geo.dist <- dist.mat(distances = data2[ , 1], dimension = 12)
gen.dist <- dist.mat(distances = data2[ , 2], dimension = 12)
```

Afterward, I checked my 2 distance matrices and the numbers are correct.

Whenever I try to run the test, I get this message:

Error in density.default(nullstats) : 'x' contains missing values

I assumed it has something to do with the dimension of the matrix, so I changed it from 12 to 11, again I got error message that says:

Error in lcomb[i, 1] : subscript out of bounds

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?
cheers